# Decrease the Space Between a Menu Item's Icon and its Text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menuitem

In my .net windows form (I am using XP Pro SP3 and VS 2010), I have created a menustrip.  In the menustrip are several menu items, each with a dropdown menu.  The menu items in the dropdown menus each have an icon with some text.  I want to make the menu more compact by decreasing the horizontal space between the icon and the text.  (I added a red arrow to the picture to show the space I am talking about).

[image]

So far, I have set the padding of all the menuitems to 0, but this seems only to affect the vertical spacing between one menu item and the next.

I want to use the *system* `rendermode` for the menustrip (although the problem persists no matter what `rendermode` I use.  The icons in the menu are 16x16, and have the property `sizetofit`.

Funny thing is that this very same spacing is just the way I want it in the `menustrip` - the icon is right next to the text.

This will remove the image margin completely, but it removes the images too; I just want to change the width of the image margin.

```
    For Each menuItem As ToolStripMenuItem In menu_main.Items
        DirectCast(menuItem.DropDown, ToolStripDropDownMenu).ShowImageMargin = False
    Next
```

What can I do here?

Comment: Just as an aside, it’s not a very good idea to customise established UI idioms this way. I know that Microsoft itself does it all the time but it’s much better to adhere to the operating system’s UI standards in these regards.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph In general, I agree with you.  In fact, I really like my XP's look for menus, and would rather leave it alone, but the menu that VS tells me is the system's own rendering doesn't look like the dropdown menus of other programs.  There is almost a quarter inch of space between the icon and the text.  It's not like that anywhere else except for microsoft office.  The spacing should be about a sixteenth, or an eighth at most.

Comment: Ah, I remember: This sounds as though it’s the area for checkboxes (which can exist in menus). Have you made sure that there isn’t an option to disable this behaviour, rather than modifying the drawing? I haven’t worked with .NET in quite some time, I can’t remember whether this exists or not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I think that area is used for checkboxes too, but it the space where icons go as well.  I have all checkbox properties set to false.  I've looked everywhere and can't find any way to diminish the space.

Comment: Please include a picture. I am giving you some support with a +1.

Comment: Neolisk - thank you.  At your request I added the image.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is kinda cheating, and probably isn't going to look as clean as you'd like, but I was able to do it by making the image have the text and then setting following properties in the designer for the menu item:

`DisplayStyle = Image`

`ImageScaling = None`

[image]

Comment: I gave you my +1 for creativity.  That's a real solution!  However, it removes the possiblity for dynamic text in the menu items, and it makes it difficult to reuse the icons for other purposes.  Not quite was I was hoping for, but an admirable solution.